# Docker gets Flask server running, but I can't connect to it with my browser

Tags: docker, flask, dockerfile

I am trying to run my flask application through Docker. I had it working last week, but now it is giving me some issues. I can start the server, but I can't seem to visit any content through my browser.

Here is my `app.py` file (reduced):

```
... imports ...
app = Flask(__name__)
DATABASE = "users.db"
app.secret_key = os.environ["SECRET_KEY"]
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = 'static/Content'

BASE_PATH = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

# For Dropbox
__TOKEN = os.environ["dbx_access_token"]
__dbx = None 

... functions ...


if __name__ == '__main__':
     app.run(port=5001, threaded=True, host=('0.0.0.0'))
```

Here is my `Dockerfile`:

```
# Use an official Python runtime as a parent image
FROM python:3

# Set the working directory to /VOSW-2016-original
WORKDIR /VOSW-2016-original

# Copy the current directory contents into the container at /VOSW-2016-original
ADD . /VOSW-2016-original

# Putting a variables in the environment
ENV SECRET_KEY="XXXXXXXX"
ENV dbx_access_token="XXXXXXXX"

# Install any needed packages specified in requirements.txt
RUN pip install --trusted-host pypi.python.org -r requirements.txt

# Make port 8000 available to the world outside this container
EXPOSE 8000

# Run app.py when the container launches
CMD ["python", "app.py", "--host=0.0.0.0"]
```

Here are the commands I am using to start the server:

```
docker build -t vosw_original ./VOSW-2016-original/
```

and then:

```
docker run -i -t -p 5001:8000 vosw_original
```

Then I get the message:

```
* Running on http://0.0.0.0:5001/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

So the server seems to be running, but I can't seem to visit it when I do any of the following:

1. `http://0.0.0.0:5001/`
2. `http://0.0.0.0:8000/`
3. `http://127.0.0.1:5001/`
4. `http://127.0.0.1:8000/`

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are running your app on the wrong port:

```
app.run(port=5001, threaded=True, host=('0.0.0.0'))
```

while exposing 8000. So by `-p 5001:8000` you are mapping container's 8000 port (on which nothing is listening) to host's 5001 port. While your app is actually running on port 5001 **within the container** which is what the message is about.